# Python list limit specific elements to N times

Tags: python, list

I have a list with 7 items inside like `['S1','S1','S1','S1','L','L','L']` and I want to limit `'L'` to be only 2 times and the rest to be `'S1'`.

Comment: What do you mean by limit? do you want a new list that only has the occurrence of `L` 2 times?

Comment: This description is a bit vague, can you elaborate?

Comment: @DirtyBit exactly this is what I want, by verify the actual list if it haves more than 2 L in list, if it is more than 2, create a new list with only 2 L and the rest to be S1

Comment: Not clear: Do you want to _remove_ all but the first two `L`, or do you want to _replace_ them with more `S1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a counter to count the occurrences of `L` elem in the list and append accordingly:

```
s = ['S1','S1','S1','S1','L','L','L']

c = 0
res = []
for el in s:
    if el != 'L':
        res.append(el)
    elif c < 2:
        c += 1
        res.append(el)   
print(res)
```

OUTPUT:

```
['S1', 'S1', 'S1', 'S1', 'L', 'L']
```

**Edit**:

if you want to replace the rest of the `L` to the `S1`:

```
s = ['S1','S1','S1','S1','L','L','L']

c = 0
res = []
for el in s:
    if el != 'L':
        res.append(el)
    else:
        if c < 2:
            c += 1
            res.append(el)
        else:
            res.append("S1")

print(res)
```

OUTPUT:

```
['S1', 'S1', 'S1', 'S1', 'L', 'L', 'S1']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
lst = ["S1","S1","S1","S1","L","L","L"]

limit = 2
value = "L"

new_lst = []
counter = 0
for i in lst:
    if counter == limit and i == value:
        continue
    if i == value:
        counter += 1
    new_lst.append(i)

print(new_lst)
```